# Сортировка многомерного массива в PHP

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Функция `array_multisort` возвращает `false` при попытке отсортировать многомерный массив и сортировки не происходит.
Как узнать, в чем проблема?

Вот код:

```
// $arResult["ITEMS"] - многомерный массив произвольного уровня вложенности
$sort_numcie = array();
foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $val) {
    $sort_numcie[] = $val['SORT'];
}
array_multisort($sort_numcie, SORT_ASC, $arResult["ITEMS"]); // false
```

Что именно не нравится этой функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном примере вы не вкладываете данные в массив $sort_numcie под нужными ключами. И вложенность тут непричем.

```
$sort_numcie = array();
foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $key => $val) {
    $sort_numcie[$key] = $val['SORT'];
}
array_multisort($sort_numcie, SORT_ASC, $arResult["ITEMS"]);
```

И array_multisort не будет сортировать вложенные массивы. Если вы хотите сортировать и вложенные массивы, то надо применять сортировку к каждому отдельно, как в примере в документации:

```
$ar = array(
       array("10", 11, 100, 100, "a"),
       array(   1,  2, "2",   3,   1)
      );
array_multisort($ar[0], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,
                $ar[1], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);
```

Comment: В моём примере $sort_numcie получает вот такие данные: array(0=>3, 1=>4, 2=>1, 3=>2), соответствующие четырём элементам массива $arResult["ITEMS"] (ключи массивов тоже соответствуют). Согласно [примеру](http://joxi.ru/vAWYg8kT10XqGm) из документации все должно работать. Но выдает false. Как включить вывод описания проблемы?

Comment: Решил включить вывод E_WARNING и наткнулся на "array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent". Действительно, проблема оказалась в несоотвествии ключей $sort_numcie и $arResult["ITEMS"].

Answer (score 0):

```
$price = array();
foreach ($inventory as $key => $row)
{
    $price[$key] = $row['price'];
}

array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $inventory);
```

Comment: В каких случаях array_multisort вернёт false?

Comment: Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки.

Comment: Это я и сам прочитал в документации. А конкретнее? Что за ошибки? Как включить вывод описания проблемы? Или где можно прочитать список неочевидных требований к параметрам этой функции?